# How does the Intel 8086/88 know when to assert the IO/M signal?

Tags: io, x86, intel

Consider an Intel 8088 processor with a standard, parallel RAM and ROM implementation that also supports address/data bus access to various external peripherals like analog-to-digital converters (ADCs), UARTs, and more.

I'm having trouble designing a chip-select decoding scheme that I'm confident will work. Although I could use logic gates across all 20 address lines, the resulting PCB has significantly more traces and ICs, along with a greater potential of my design being incorrect. I'd like to utilize the IO/M pin to make my design easier to design and debug.

The 8086/88 datasheet describes the basic function of the IO/M pin but doesn't explain the underlying mechanism behind it. I understand that a logic low on the pin indicates a memory access and a logic high indicates I/O access, but I don't understand where the processor comes up with this information. The memory map I'm trying to work with has 2kB of address space reserved to address peripherals. Both ADC's require 8 bytes each to address individual analog inputs, and the UART needs a 1-byte placeholder.

```
0x00000 - 0x7FFFF : SRAM Chip 0 (512kB)
0x80000 - 0xDFFFF : SRAM Chip 1 (384kB)
------------------------------
0xE0000           : ADC 0  (8 Bytes)
0xE0008           : ADC 1  (8 Bytes)
0xE0010           : UART 0 (1 Byte)
------------------------------
0xE0800 - 0xFFFFF : Flash ROM (126kB)
```

Since memory maps can be arbitrary, how does the processor magically know when it's trying to access memory vs. I/O devices? By extension, how does the Intel 8088 know what to do with it's IO/M pin if I could easily swap the ordering of the above address space?

Comment: My experience of doing I/O at the CPU level is pretty much confined to the fantastic Z80, where you use separate instructions for the two classes of access: `LD` for memory and `OUT`/`IN` for... well, guess. And presumably the instruction used dictates what its own `IORQ` pin does. But given your question, I presume you've exhausted all the literature, and the 8086/8 makes no such distinction, right? If so, then that would make for a very interesting question.

Comment: @underscore_d That may actually be the answer to my question. I've dug quite a bit into the documentation regarding connecting the ICs, but haven't researched x86 instructions enough to know if specific instructions are "flagged" as I/O and others are memory. I'll research and update my question when I find out!

Comment: @WebsterXC I didn't _think_ there was any other possible answer, but I had to presume you'd read everything. ;-) But yeah, it's almost certainly that. I can't think of any other option. I think there might be CPUs out there that make no distinction, but then they presumably can't have an equivalent pin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to my suspicions based on a past (and future?) life in Z80 ASM and a quick search for *8086 io*, I found a handy synopsis of 8086 I/O at this page by Dr. Jim Plusquellic (hooray for free lecture notes!) - http://ece-research.unm.edu/jimp/310/slides/8086_IO1.html - which I'll now try to... synopsise even more handily.

As his page explains, the 8086 has two available modes of I/O:

- memory-mapped
- "isolated" [a.k.a. standard](http://8051-microcontrollers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/8086-io-ports-important-points-to-be.html#.V6T-VHSVu00)

In the latter case, a special set of instructions must be used - `IN`, `INS`, `OUT`, and `OUTS`. These cause corresponding signals to be output on the `M/IO` (Memory or I/O) and `R/W` (Read/Write) pins. That page indicates the difference and how these can be wired up:

[image]

As the Prof. explains, using this mode avoids using up normal memory ranges for I/O, with the *caveat*s that:

- it increases circuit complexity: you must wire up the mentioned pins to disambiguate between the two possible meanings of an address and direct each to the right destination. In doing so, you conceptually create the 'virtual pins' `IORC` or `IOWC` (I/O Read/Write Control) shown in the diagram.
- it limits the instructions you can use for I/O to the 4 mentioned, rather than letting you do all kinds of acrobatics with normal memory loads/stores/etc., as you could under memory-mapped I/O (assuming the target device will tolerate them!)

So, the reason the 8086 and friends know when to assert `IO/M` is... because you tell them when, by using one of their dedicated I/O instructions.

Comment: Thank you so much this is an awesome collection of information and exactly the answer I was hoping for!

Comment: @WebsterXC You're welcome. It was educational for me, too! Credit is due, of course, to Dr. Jim Plusquellic, whose notes I built this on.

Comment: Marked the answer as accepted, but not enough rep for a public upvote yet. I'll revisit it soon!